# WordPress "Hide WP" Gives Me Error After Admin Login

Tags: admin, login, errors, 404-error

I recently paid a freelancer to install a "hide WP" effect, which hides the fact that I am using WordPress. I specifically asked to install something with this effect: http://codecanyon.net/item/hide-my-wp-no-one-can-know-you-use-wordpress/4177158

My domain is http://www.catsbuzz.com. The freelancer did the installation, and going to catsbuzz.com/wp-admin gave a 404 error. And when I went to catsbuzz.com/administrator, I was able to log in and use the dashboard.

I knew something was weird when my AdSense account got banned all of a sudden.. Today I went to catsbuzz.co/administrator to log in. The log in page works, but after I type the username/password and click "log in", it goes to a 404 page.. And going to catsbuzz.com/wp-admin or /wp-admin.php both gives 404 error. So now I am stuck, unable to go into my dashboard.

Please help me.. I do not have any knowledge in solving this problem at all.. I am dealing with getting a refund, but meanwhile I really need to fix this error. I simply need to be able to log in to my WordPress dashboard, I don't care about the "Hide WP" effect anymore.

Can please anyone help me? I thank anyone in advance.

Comment: Is there anyone who knows how one can achieve this effect in the first place so we can just reverse it?

Comment: there are only so may ways to customize wordpress.  The person could have used a Plugin, or more likely, with changes to a themes functions.php file.  Lots will depend on how your theme is structured.  If done right you chose a theme that was close, and it was modified with a child theme. If you had a sloppy developer, they would have directly made changes to a formal theme without using a child theme modifier.  How was your site customized? (custom theme or a packaged theme pure, or a packaged theme with internal modifications, or best a packaged theme with child theme mods?)

Comment: When you FTP to the site what directories do you see in the wp-content folder?  What in the wp-content/plugin folder, what is in the wp-content/theme folder?

Comment: I'm sorry but your question seems off-topic. Asking about third party plugins, themes or work is really difficult to answer. Also, the plugin you are talking about is not free so you should ask to them. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just registered, because I have seen your question. I have not use Hide WP yet, but I know if you are trying to use custom codes to hide your Wordpress it won't work easily, it will probably have flaws and problems (plugina nd theme compatibility problems too).
If you have bought Hide WP (I mean the premium plugin) and get it installed. Does Hide WP change files or folders? If no, maybe it would be a solution if you could deactivate the plugin.
If you cannot access your dashboard, just use the FTP and go into the wp-admin/plugins folder. You should rename the folder name of the Hide WP plugin (for example put a number for ex.: 1 after the plugin's name).
If you have a fresh database backup, I advise you to restore it (if you are hosted at Godaddy/Hostgator go into your hostin control panel -> databases, I recommend to back up first your database if you are unsure about it and then after you have backed it up, try to restore a previous [for example 22 hours old] savefile).
I hope I could help.

If you are using the code that your freelancer gave, I do not know what to do exactly. I think database restore might could help, but if he renamed folders, added extra lines to the wordpress it will be unuseful.

Comment: Hello, I actually do not know if it changes files or folders. I just let the freelancer do the work.

Comment: I just checked the plugins folder, but I don't see anything that resembles the hiding effect. I think the freelancer didn't use a "plugin".

Comment: :/ if I were you I would ask (or even demand) that freelancer to solve the problem

Comment: Wouldn't there be a way to find any edits that the freelancer has made and fix that? I simply have no knowledge to solve this. Would one have to go to phpMyAdmin to achieve the "hide WP" effect in the first place?

Comment: I am writing this, because only he knows what he has used to 'achieve the effect', if you are thinking about hiding that you are using wordpress (which is quite pointless and could also cause compatibility issues) you should go with that premium plugin. In my opinion just use Block Bad Queries [MUST-HAVE](for deflecting injection and bad URL attacks), Better WP Security [Maybe] (you should deactivate brute force protection, because the plugin could ban you - the admin - from the site) and Captcha [MUST-HAVE] for your login form

Answer (score 0):

Huh, 2 or 1 and a half year ago I was thinking about hiding that I am using wordpress (the pemium plugin was not existed) and there were several - I would call them - trash articles and solutions to do that, I am looking up them now, but I cannot promise that I will find something useful :/

EDIT: sorry bad button, I should have made it a comment

Comment: I think you should reupload wordpress overwriting the old files, or maybe it would be better to delete all the stuffs except the wp-content directory (which is maybe already renamed to for example "content" by the freelancer) and wp-config.php, so you still have your theme, your plugins and your configuration and then upload the other wordpress files

Comment: add me on skype if you have no success with it (laciiiiiii7) cuz maybe I can help and cuz I love catz